# Stuck in 7days series tutorial Blender

Tags: blender

currently I've been following this day6 tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYEaY6RTUzc&t=2169s and I am stuck in 36:09 .

Problem is when I try to extrude that circle the extrusion doesn't come like the one in the tutorial although I think I did everything the same .
This is the result I get https://youtu.be/5AwpbDEInP0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the shrinkwrap modifier before extrude faces. If the problem persists, try extruding along normals from `Alt + e` or extrude along the z axis with `e + z`, then press `3` to right view and adjust it with `g + z`.

Comment: Thank you , applying the modifier and extruding faces along normals solved my problem